# Use of 50% confidence interval to detect marginally-significant fixed effects in linear mixed models?

Tags: statistical-significance, mixed-model, confidence-interval

I read this research paper today: [Fates of trees damaged by logging in Amazonian Bolivia](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.foreco.2015.08.009). In my understanding, the authors used the following approach to determine if fixed predictors in an LMM are significant, marginally-significant or non-significant:

1. They calculate 95% CI and 50% CI for the coefficients of fixed effects.
2. If the 95% CI doesn't contain 0, they consider the respective fixed effect to be significant.
3. If the 95% CI contains 0 but the 50% CI doesn't, they consider the fixed effect to be marginally-significant.
4. If the 50% CI contains 0, they consider the fixed effect to be not significant.

I haven't found any further information about this approach (neither in the method section of the paper, nor anywhere else). Those are my questions:

1. In my (limited) understanding, talking about marginal significance in cases where p-values are only slightly higher than the 'significance' threshold is [frowned upon](https://mchankins.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/still-not-significant-2/). Is talking about marginal significance more accepted when using the 50% confidence interval?
2. If the answer to 1) is yes, how can this approach be justified in a paper? Are there any references to cite, or links to sources that provide a justification?